# AJAX Post Request Not Returning JSON Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is my AJAX request:

```
var data = modalDom.find("form").serializeObject();
data["returnJson"] = true;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/companies/edit/",
    data: data,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (result) {
        modalDom.modal('hide');

        var dropdown = $("#create-modal #CompanyID");
        var currentSelected = dropdown.find("option:selected");
        if (currentSelected.length) {
            currentSelected.removeAttr("selected");
        }

        var newOption = '<option value="' + result.company.CompanyID + '">' + result.company.Name + '</option>';
        dropdown.append(newOption);
        dropdown.val(result.company.CompanyID);
    }
});
```

And here is the controller it is hitting:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Company company) {
    if (CurrentUser.IsCompany(User)) {
        return AjaxJsonResult.AuthFailResult();
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return AjaxJsonResult.FailResult(ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage).ToList());
    }

    db.Company_CompanyType.RemoveRange(db.Company_CompanyType.Where(c => c.CompanyID == company.CompanyID));
    if (Request.Params["CompanyTypes[]"] != null) {
        var companyTypes = (from item in Request.Params["CompanyTypes[]"].Split(new[] {','})
            select db.CompanyTypes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == item)
            into ct
            where ct != null
            select new Company_CompanyType() {
                CompanyID = company.CompanyID, CompanyTypeID = ct.CompanyTypeID
            }).ToList();

        db.Company_CompanyType.AddRange(companyTypes);
    }

    if (company.CompanyID <= 0) {
        db.Companies.Add(company);
    }
    else {
        db.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    db.SaveChanges();

    return AjaxJsonResult.SuccessResult("?companyID=" + company.CompanyID);
}
```

I am unable to access any properties of my JSON object through the result variable. When I log the data I am passing in the console, it is the correct data from the form. When log the result variable in the console I get this:

```
Object {Success: true, RedirectTo: "?companyID=9818", Messages: null}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: My goal is to have the result object return data submitted from the form. Example:

```
result.company.CompanyID = 1988
result.company.Name = "My Company Name"
```

Source code for AjaxJsonResult.SuccessResult() method:

```
public class AjaxJsonResult {
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string RedirectTo { get; set; }
    public List<string> Messages { get; set; }

    public static JsonResult SuccessResult(string redirectTo) {
        var result = new AjaxJsonResult {
            Success = true,
            RedirectTo = redirectTo,
            Messages = null
        };
        return ToJsonResult(result);
    }

    public static JsonResult ToJsonResult(AjaxJsonResult result, JsonRequestBehavior behavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) {
        return new JsonResult() {
            Data = result,
            ContentType = (string) null,
            ContentEncoding = (Encoding) null,
            JsonRequestBehavior = behavior
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would like the result json data to look like?

Comment: @elolos I made some edits to my original post. Hopefully that makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies what you're trying to achieve. Can you please also post the source code for the `AjaxJsonResult.SuccessResult()` method?

Comment: @elolos Sure. I added it in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json object available to javascript can only have the same properties as the object serialized by the controller. So if you return an `AjaxJsonResult`, you will only have access to `result.Success`, `result.RedirectTo` and `result.Messages`. If you need the company object to be serialized you have two options:

1. Return a plain `JsonResult` without success, redirect and messages information and just rely on http status codes. This would involve changing the action method and it wouldn't work if you are using the success, redirect and messages data in javascript.
2. Update the `AjaxJsonResult` so it has an extra property to store content, and also pass this in the `SuccessResult` method. It can be strongly typed to the Company class or it could be a plain object.

Here's an example:

```
 public static JsonResult SuccessResult(string redirectTo, object data) 
 {
     var result = new AjaxJsonResult 
     {
         Data = data,
         Success = true,
         RedirectTo = redirectTo,
         Messages = null
     };
     return ToJsonResult(result);
 }
```

Then you have to pass the object in the method like so:

```
return AjaxJsonResult.SuccessResult("?companyID=" + company.CompanyID, new {company});
```

You would then be able to access the object's properties in javascript, but you have to be mindful of using the appropriate case and to also add the new Data property. If you do this, you will be able to get the company ID by typing `result.Data.company.CompanyID`